# Why do weak acids like ethanol not act as a strong base in water?

Tags: organic-chemistry, acid-base, ph, physical-organic-chemistry

In water, ethanol has a $\mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{a} = 15.9$ which means that its $\mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{b}$ is $-1.9$. Which implies that all weak acids in water are in fact strong bases. But this is not true, weak acids in fact do act like *weak acids*. That would mean that this equation isn't true always.

$$14 = \mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{a} + \mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{b}$$

Considering this is just the ionic product of water it should be valid always?

Comment: It's the $\mathrm pK_\mathrm b$ of the conjugate base, not ethanol itself. $$\mathrm pK_\mathrm a(\ce{EtOH}) + \mathrm pK_\mathrm b(\ce{EtO-}) = 14$$

Comment: And because pKa > 14, $\ce{EtO-}$ isn't going to exist in aqueous solution to any practical measure, making it a very strong base. $$\ce{EtO- + H2O -> EtOH + OH-}$$

Comment: and ethanol is a *very* weak acid, hence it's conjugate base is strong. A weak acid like EtOOH also has a weak conjugate base.

Comment: @Karl did you mean _strong_ conjugate base in the last line of your comment?

Comment: @WilliamR.Ebenezer Definitely not.

Comment: @Karl Alright. The "very weak" makes sense then.

Comment: @WilliamR.Ebenezer ;-) Confuses me again every few years.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There seems to be a misunderstanding: The conjugate of a strong base like EtONa can't be a weak acid, because weak acids, like acetic acid for example, are still quite acidic.

- Strong acid (HCl) - very weak conjugate base (chloride anion)
- strong base (EtONa) - very weak conj. acid (Ethanol)

A strong acid or base reacts strongly (with water), the resulting conjugate is rather inert, with the equillibrium fully on the side of the latter.

- weak acid (acetic acid) - weak conj. base (acetate anion)
- weak base (ammonia) - weak conj. base (ammonium)

A weak acid or base just reacts partly towards its conjugate, so does the pure conjugate: They are both rather weak. The equillibrium in an equimolar mixture is rather stable: A buffer solution.

The *ideal* weak base or acid has a $pKa$ of 7 (in water), that is $1/2$ of the -log ion product of the given solvent. If it's even weaker, the conjugate becomes stronger again.