# Comparing Acidic and Basic Strength of organic compounds

Tags: organic-chemistry

If I find out the order of acidic strength of some organic compounds and simply flip them to get the order of basic strength, will it be correct?
Is there any case where this logic should be incorrect?

Comment: It depends how you apply this logic of yours, and such orders of acidic strength have serious limitations.

Comment: You'll rarely get asked about the acidity and basicity of _the same compounds_. See also: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/128120/strength-of-weak-acids-and-bases-is-methane-better-base-than-ammonia/128141#128141